# Pause VBA code without pausing spreadsheet

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA code where it is copying and pasting data from a spreadsheet that pulls data from an external server. Consequently, that spreadsheet takes awhile (from 10-30 seconds) to load the data.

I have researched how to pause a macro - application.wait, sleep, etc - but they also pause the spreadsheet functions so the data from the external server cannot load. Therefore when the code copies the data, it pastes `#DIV/0`!. Is there a function that can interrupt/stop/pause the macro to give the server data time to load?

I also would like this macro to run without needing user input (some suggestions online had the user advancing the code each iteration).

```
Sub all()

    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Set wb1 = Workbooks("all")

    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Set wb2 = Workbooks("other")

    For i = 2 To 5

        Application.Wait Now() + TimeValue("00:01:00")

        wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(4, 2).Copy
        wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 18).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Does `application.wait` not work? Or just not pause long enough? What's the 'error' with how you have your code now?

Comment: This is easy to do if the macro can tell when the "pull" is complete.  Is there some cell that starts empty, but gains a value when the "pull" is complete ??

Comment: What problem are you actually trying to solve? How can we reproduce it? What are you pausing the VBA for? What do you expect to happen while it is paused?

Comment: Application.wait works perfectly in that it pauses the entire sheet - however, I need the other spreadsheet to continue updating while the macro itself pauses. @Gary'sStudent there's a cell that changes values once the pull is complete, would that work? *daniel cook I need to pause the macro so that the other spreadsheet can pull data from an external server but that can take awhile. Therefore, if it continues before the data updates, I am only copying and pasting an error.

Comment: Re-reading this, you have **A)** `Workbook 1`, which pulls data from a DB/web site/other, and **B)** `Workbook 2`, which starts doing something, then needs to pause until `Workbook 1` is done. Correct? Which WB starts the process? Does `Workbook 2` initiate the processing in `Workbook 1`? Is it the other way around? Does `WB 1` just randomly get updated and `WB 2` needs to pause until the update is done?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion - `Workbook 1` is copying and pasting data from `Workbook 2` and `Workbook 2` is the one pulling data from a DB so the macro on `Workbook 1` needs to pause its C+P until `Workbook 2` is finished pulling the data. `Workbook 2` starts to pull the data when the macro inputs data into a specific cell in its spreadsheet - I left that out of the original post code to simplify it.

Comment: Since VBA is single threaded, if you have `WB1` call `WB2.LoadData` to refresh itself, all processing in `WB1` will pause while `WB2.LoadData` is running, and won't resume until it has completed. That would resolve the issue. i.e. Instead of having `WB2.LoadData` be triggered by a cell change, have it be called (passing the value that is to be put in the cell), have it populate the cell, then continue to do its thing. When it's done executing, control returns to `WB1`.

Comment: That would work! Is the function named loaddata? My macro doesn't recognize `wb2.LoadData`.

Answer (score 2):

`Application.Wait` suspends processing in Excel. This means that your background processing will suspend, too.

Instead, try this:

```
Dim WaitTime as Date
For i = 2 To 5

    WaitTime = Now() + TimeValue("00:01:00")
    While Now() < WaitTime
        DoEvents
    Wend

    wb2.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(4, 2).Copy
    wb1.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 18).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

Next i
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'm using Excel 2010 - Application.DoEvents causes error 438: Object doesn't support this property or method - so is there an alternative I can use?

Comment: My bad. Remove `Application.`  It should just be `DoEvents`. I was looking at your `Application.Wait` and went with that.  I've updated the code.

Comment: I tried your code and it has the same issue as 'Application.Wait' in that it doesn't let the other spreadsheet update until after the minute. Any ideas? Would it help if the user needed to press or input something before the macro continues?